# Undefined index: media Twitter API

Tags: api, laravel, twitter, media, entities

i confused with my apps, i have a problem with displaying image_url data from Twitter API.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$events = Event::findOrFail($id);
$query = $events->hashtag;

// Application Programming Interface
$stack = HandlerStack::create();

$middleware = new Oauth1([
  'consumer_key'    => 'CONSUMER_KEY',
  'consumer_secret' => 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
  'token'           => 'TOKEN',
  'token_secret'    => 'TOKEN_SECRET'
]);

$stack->push($middleware);

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/',
    'handler' => $stack,
    'auth' => 'oauth'
]);

$res = $client->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23', [
  'query' => ['q' => $query]
]);
$array = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$tes = (count($array['statuses']));

    if($request->user()->cannot('show', $events)){
        abort(405);
    }else{
  return view('dashboard.events.show', compact('events'), [
    'events' => $events
    ])->with([
      'array'=> $array,
      'tes' => $tes
    ]);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
    @for ($i = 0; $i < $tes; $i++)
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="{{$array['statuses'][$i]['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']}}" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
@endfor
```

**RESULT**

```
Error Messages:
Undefined index: media
```

At twitter API v1.1 media entities is disappear when people not post picture, so when i trying to get json data with looping concept and media_url object is undefined, and than i result is error message.
sorry my english so bad, i'm still newbie in php and api.

Comment: Show what `dd($array['statuses'][$i]['entities']`) displays please.

Comment: Please post `dd` result. Also, do you use `['media']` in a same view or controller?

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "hashtags" => array:5 [▶]
  "symbols" => []
  "user_mentions" => []
  "urls" => array:1 [▶]
]

Comment: yes, i use ['media'] only at view in looping syntax

Comment: You posted `dd($array['statuses'][$i]['entities'])` and there is no `media` property there. So, why are you using ['media']?

Comment: to get media_url, but sometimes [media'] property not there,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine and you're saying that sometimes there is no ['media'] property, so you want to use something like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $tes; $i++)
    @if(isset($array['statuses'][$i]['entities']['media']))
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{{$array['statuses'][$i]['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']}}" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    @endif
@endfor
```

So, when there is a picture in a `$array`, your view will generate HTML to display it. If you don't have, it will be skipped.

Comment: alexey mazenin

thanks you're awesome, my apps now works with your code..
i can get media_url now., thanks you're briliant man.